# Is there a general formula for the following finite series?

Tags: probability

I was computing the expectation of a random variable $X$ and got the following sum $$E(X)= 1\cdot \frac{1}{n} + 2\cdot \frac{1}{n-1}+3\cdot \frac{1}{n-2}+...+(n-1)\cdot \frac{1}{2}+n\cdot \frac{1}{1}.$$

The problem was something like this: you are stuck outside your room trying out $n$ keys in the following way: you pick the first key randomly (hence $1/n$), if it works then you stop otherwise you remove this key and then randomly choose the second key (hence $1/(n-1)$) and check if it works and so on.

I was just curious to know if there is a closed form for the expectation.

Comment: That is not the way to calculate the expectation: you must use the _initial_ values of the probabilities, which are all $1/n$. Your probabilities don't add up to $1$!

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{n+1-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{n+1-k}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{n+1}{k}-\dfrac{k}{k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{n+1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n1\\
&=(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k}-n\\
&=(n+1)H_n-n\\
&=(n+1)(\ln(n)+\gamma+\dfrac1{2n}+O(\frac1{n^2}))-n\\
&=n\ln(n)+n\gamma+\dfrac1{2}+\ln(n)+\gamma+O(\dfrac1{n})-n\\
&=n\ln(n)-n(1-\gamma)+\ln(n)+\dfrac1{2}+\gamma+O(\dfrac1{n})\\
\end{array}
$

Here
$H_n$ is the harmonic series
(see [Asymptotic estimate of the sequence of harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596621/asymptotic-estimate-of-the-sequence-of-harmonic-series-sum-k-1n-frac1))
and
$\gamma =\approx 0.577$
is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.